# is it possible to filter documents from collection depends on other collection values

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

is it possible to filter documents from collection A depends on other collection value ?

for example .. i have 2 collection

1- `users collection` .. contains users uids as documents and field called videoUrl

2- per user in  `users collection` has `subcollection` called  `follow` and it contains the users uid that this user follow

Now i have list in UI like `timeline` displaying the users videoUrl field from `users collection` to the user .. but i want only filter the docs if it's doc id exist in `follow` `subcollection` of the current user

what i am doing now is complicated thing like single query into loop but i don't feel happy with this way .

i am wondering if `Firestore rules` could done this job ?? i have no idea if yes or on

this is my rules .. it is basic

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: 1) [Rules don't filter data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#rules_are_not_filters), so that can't help here. 2) Firestore queries can only filter based on data inside the documents that they return. There is no way to filter your `users` documents based on data in documents in their `follow` subcollection, or any other collection for that matter. Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69926798/firestore-how-to-filter-documents-by-existing-in-other-collection