# Subscribe to snaphot changes, where subcollection contains specific field

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a chat app, where users can create chats. When user creates chat, a subcollection of chat members is created, where information about members is stored (id, prefered name, photoUrl).

In React Native, onMount I try to subscribe to changes to those documents, where subcollection has a document with field `id` == `uid` of authed user.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(
      query(
        collection(FIRESTORE_DB, FIRESTORE_COLLECTIONS.GROUPS),
        where(FIRESTORE_COLLECTIONS.GROUP_MEMBERS, 'array-contains', user?.uid)
      ),
      (data) => {
        logMessage(data.docs.map((doc) => doc.data())); // will be state setter
      }
    );

    return () => unsubscribe();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);
```

Is it even possible to do? Or should I change the data model to just store `id`s of members in array?

Answer (score 1):

Firestore queries can only filter on data that is present in the documents that they return. So they cannot filter on documents in a subcollection.

You will indeed have to duplicate the member IDs into the parent document(s) to allow this use-case.

Also see:

- [firestore query document that have a collection contains a document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71215138/firestore-query-document-that-have-a-collection-contains-a-document).
- [Firestore: how to filter documents by existing in other collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69926798/firestore-how-to-filter-documents-by-existing-in-other-collection)